# Текст сбоку от поля ввода

Tags: html, форма

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтоб текст логина и пароля были сбоку от поля ввода?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы об этом?

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
Логин <input name="login" type="text">
Пароль <input name="password" type="password">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Form </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            form, form ul, form li, fieldset, textarea { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            form ul, form li { list-style-type: none; }
            form li { clear: both; height: 1%; overflow: auto; }
            fieldset { border : 0; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="loginForm">
        <fieldset><legend><span> Sign In </span></legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="username"> Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user" id="username" value="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="password"> Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" value="">
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" class="button terminalButton" value="Log in">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```